# Python number to word converter needs a space detector

Tags: python, indexing, converters

I have been working on a sort of encryption tool in python. This bit of code is for the decryption feature.

The point is to take the given numbers and insert them into a list from where they will be divided by the given keys.

My idea for code is below but I keep getting the `out of list index range` whenever I try it out. Any suggestions? Keep in mind I'm a beginner:

```
need = []
detr = raw_input('What would you like decrypted?')
count = 0
for d in detr:
    if (d == '.' or d == '!') or (d.isalpha() or d== " "):
        count +=1
    else:
        need[count].append(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are attempting to overwrite list values that don't exist.

`list.append(item)` adds `item` to the end of `list`. `list[index] = item` inserts item into `list` at position `index`.

```
list = [0,0,0]
list.append(0) # = [0,0,0,0]
list[0] = 1 # [1,0,0,0]
list[99] = 1 # ERROR: out of list index range
```

You should get rid of the `count` variable entirely. You could append `None` in the case of `d==' '` etc. or just ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understood your description you want to extract the numbers in a string and append them to a list using a for-loop to iterate over each character.

I think it would be easier doing it with regular expressions (something like `r'([\d]+)'`).
But the way joconner said: *"get rid of the count variable"*:

```
need = []
detr = input('What would you like decrypted?\n')
i = iter(detr) # get an iterator
# iterate over the input-string
for d in i:
    numberstr = ""
    try:
        # as long as there are digits
        while d.isdigit():
            # append them to a cache-string
            numberstr+= d
            d = next(i)
    except StopIteration:
            # occurs when there are no more characters in detr
            pass
    if numberstr != "":
        # convert the cache-string to an int
        # and append the int to the need-array  
        need.append( int(numberstr) )

# print the need-array to see what is inside
print(need)
```